# when to type await ? with using aiohttp in python

Tags: python, aiohttp

I use aiohttp . at what places of app do I need to type await ?
as I know there are cases:

1. when code is about session

   ```
       async def get(self):
           session = await get_session(self.request)
   ```
2. when code is about database

```
   def __init__(self, db, **kwargs):
           self.collection = db[MESSAGE_COLLECTION]

   async def save(self, user, msg, **kw):
           result = await self.collection.insert({'user': user, 'msg': msg, 'time': datetime.now()})
```

3. when code is about sockets

```
   async def get(self):
           ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
           await ws.prepare(self.request)
```

Comment: Typically you await whenever you call an async function. Regardless of its purpose.

Comment: what functions are async ? if this is not a function that defined by my code

Comment: those defined with `async` keyword? You either have to look at the functions source code or read its documentation.